# How to select html elements using jQuery in Phantomjs?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web-scraping, phantomjs

I am going to scrape some contents from a website that use javascript to load dynamic content. Before, I have used **request** and **cheerio** to scrape and they worked just fine. But I just find out that **request** and **cheerio** cannot  scrape dynamic content. After do a research, I found **phantomjs** that can get all the content after the page has loaded. I have a problem with it now, I cannot use **jQuery selector** like I used to use in **cheerio**. This is my sample code but the selector is return nothing.

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://angkorauto.com/vehicle';
page.open(url, function (status) {
    if (status !== 'success') {
        console.log('Unable to load the address!');
        phantom.exit();
    } else {
        window.setTimeout(function () {
            // console.log(page.content);
            page.includeJs('https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', function(){

                page.evaluate(function(){
                    console.log($('.divTitle').find('a').attr('href'));
                });
            });

            phantom.exit();
        }, 1500);
    }
});
```

Could you help me with this problem? I really get stuck now.

Thanks for ur time to help.

Comment: You want to scrape from only this website (ankkorauto.com) or some other websites too?

Comment: I want other too if request and cheerio cannot be used

Comment: what??? what is cheerio?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The website you want to scrape has jQuery already (like many other websites) so you don't have load it again.

This works fine:

```
var page = require('webpage').create();
var url = 'http://angkorauto.com/vehicle';
page.open(url, function(status) {

    var href = page.evaluate(function(){
        return jQuery('.divTitle').find('a').attr('href');
    });

    console.log(href);
});
```

Comment: I will try this

Comment: This code solves two problems without clearly stating why. 1. Loading a another jQuery version tends to break all jQuery functionality on the site. So if it's already available, it should not be loaded. 2. `console.log` calls inside of the page context (inside `page.evaluate`) are not printed to the console by default. They would need the `page.onConsoleMessage` event handler. (@DooDoo)